# Run time error 424 Object required

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Run time error 91 Object or block variable not set for the below line that says <- Error Here!!

```
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rhs_block")(0) ' <- Error Here!!
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")(7).getElementsByTagName("a")(2).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerHTML
    Cells(i, 2) = objH3
```

I searched in Stackoverflow but have not found an answer for this.

Complete VBA code:

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String
start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rhs_block")(0)
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")(7).getElementsByTagName("a")(2).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerHTML
    Cells(i, 2) = objH3
    DoEvents
Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time
    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So you have checked and there are at least 8 DIVs inside hte element with the **rhs_block** ID  and inside the eighth DIV there are at least 3 As and inside the third A there are at least one SPAN and that span has text. Correct?

Comment: `getElementById` doesn't return a collection. It should only return a single element. You do not need the `(0)`.

Comment: Do you get runtime error 424 or 91?

Comment: After Removing (0) from id now, it is showing runtime error 91.

Comment: @Jeeped - Question edited with image showing what i am trying to fetch is highlighted. 40 under span tag is what i am trying to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

The element IDs on a html page have be unique (otherwise it would not be an "identifier"). So one ID should be attached to one element only. However, a browser will not check this, respectivly ignore that mistake in the html file.

Anyway for your javascript function `getElementById()` this means that it will return only one single element.
You need to change:

```
Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rhs_block")(0)
```

To

```
Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rhs_block")
```

Then your `objResultDiv` should no longer throw the runtime error 91.

BTW, there are javascript functions which do return an array of elements. Like `getElementsByTagName("p")` (returns all elements with the paragraph tag) or `getElementsByName("test123")` (returns all elements with `name="test123"`).

You can tell from the function name, whether a single or multiple elements are returned. (getElementById vs. getElement**s**ByName)

Comment: @user2269164 If this helped you, please upvote and accept as answer.